# Debugging using CRM Development Kit

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, visual-studio-debugging

I just started using the included **Development Kit** that came with the CRM SDK. I created a simple plugin using the Development Kit and now I cannot find a way to debug the plugin. Before i started to use the Development Kit i was able to debug the plugins i created.
I attached the debugger to the w3wp.exe process but the debugger doesnt break on the breakpoint at all.
Moreover my assembly is registered on **Database** and with **Isolation** set to **None**
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. Turns out you have to **re-deploy** the plugin after setting the Assembly with **Isolation** set to **None**. Then like Chris Snyder said you still have to **copy** the **PDB file** from the debug folder to the **bin/assembly** folder on the CRM server. Seems like that step is still manual. Will see if I can either find a way to do it automatically or just create a simble batch file to do it.
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There is [another way to debug](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmnontechnical/b/c5insightblog/archive/2011/11/29/managing-web-resources-and-plug-ins-with-the-crm-developer-toolkit.aspx) (instructions toward the end), by copying the PDB to the CRM /bin and attaching to the asynchronous (or sandbox) worker process.  I'm not sure which way is easier...I will have to try Piyush's way sometime, but I do not use the RegistrationTool anymore thanks to the toolkit:

> Debugging works well once you follow [the setup instructions](http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/02/crm-2011-plug-in-tips-and-tricks-part-1.html), though
>   copying the PDB file remains a manual step. Also note, the sandbox
>   process (Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.WorkerProcess) is not started until
>   after a plug-in is run, so you will have to invoke it (or another one)
>   at least once before you will be able to debug.

Comment: this still doesnt work :/ is it because i may be running it not on SandBox?

Comment: You should be able to see the type (sandbox or not) in the Packaging project's register file.  Did you add the registry key and restart Async services?

Comment: Ok i found out what the problem was i forgot to re-deploy the plugin after i set the assembly to No Isolation.. dumb me... i will post an answer so that anyone else who might still have the same problem will not do my mistake. Thx man :)

Comment: The only problem going with this approach is if multiple developers are working on same environment then nobody will be able to work till debug is ON.

Answer (score 1):

Some time back I wrote an Article to debug plugins in CRM 2011, this might help you out.

[Debug Plugins - CRM Parking Lot](http://crm.ipiyush.me/debug-plugin-in-dynamics-crm-2011/)